# Cannot test flutter app on actual iphone, unable to install 'Runner' error on xcode 11.4

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I updated Xcode to 11.4 but when I went to test my flutter app on a physical device the error 'Unable to install "Runner" popped up and going into details it said No code signature found. I've already upgraded my iPhone to iOS 13.4 and there's no problem on the simulator.

I've also tried cleaning the xcode build and running flutter clean but the problem persisted. Am I missing another step?

Comment: Have you looked into [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration)?

Comment: I've already looked through the Flutter page for xcode 11.4 support and followed the instructions still cannot run on physical device the simulator running iOS 13.4 has no issues.

Answer (score 0):

@[jmagman](https://github.com/jmagman) said and I quote

"
The bug first appeared in iOS 13.3.1 and is fixed in iOS 13.4 beta 3 (17E5241d). It was not specific to Flutter, was hit at runtime loading an embedded dylib (like Flutter), and can be reproduced without Flutter. It should not impact apps that are already distributed to the App Store (meaning: your customers are not hitting this crash). You should still be able to distribute your application to the App Store.

Workarounds:

Install the beta profile on your test device and install iOS 13.4 beta 3 or higher.
Wait for iOS 13.4 to be released.
Use a non-Personal Team provisioning profile. Personal Team provisioning profile says "Personal Team" in the Xcode build settings Runner Target > General > Signing and Capabilities > Team dropdown.
Run in the simulator.
Test on an iOS device running 13.3 or lower. If you are seeing a similar crash on iOS 13.4 or greater, please file a new Flutter GitHub issue so we can take a look."

check the full thread at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49504